# Is appcast.xml worth using for PHP web app?

Tags: php, xml, release, ads, release-management

I am working on a mature photo gallery software http://fulldecent.github.com/cameralife/ which is in PHP.

This is currently advertised via Freecode (formerly Freshmeat). Usage came down a lot after the recent switch from Sourceforge, and I suspect is it because the syndication SF had. Should I be using appcast.xml (example at https://github.com/andymatuschak/Sparkle/blob/master/Sample%20Appcast.xml) to broadcast updates to the software. Are there any other things I should be doing to notify the world when I release new versions.

To be specific:

- Is appcast.xml reasonable to use for PHP projects?
- Are there other common ways to notify the world when a new release for this type of PHP project is available?

Comment: you can use appcast for that and if the application itself loads it from time to time from your server it can check for updates.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to support Composer

See: https://getcomposer.org/

Example of a project with support:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPowerPoint/blob/master/composer.json